# MySQL Data Cleansing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to cleanse some data in MySQL and I am unsure as the most efficient way to fix the following. I have three columns A, B and C. These frequently take on the same value. If A & B are the same or A & C are the same then I want to fill out the other option with the non NULL value, if possible. B & C do not affect the value for A. For example:

```
-------------------
|A    |B    |C    |
-------------------
|1    |2    |3    |
|1    |2    |NULL |
|2    |5    |8    |
|2    |NULL |8    |
|3    |NULL |9    |
|3    |NULL |NULL |
-------------------
```

In the above example row 2, column C should be filled in with 3 and row 4, column B should be 5. When I only have two options, we then fill in accordingly. Therefore row 6, column C should be 9 while row 5 column B and row 6 column B both stay NULL. How can I write a script to solve this such that if B or C is not NULL then we fill it in based on other values in the table? Thanks.

Comment: You can write an `update` statement using `case`. We would be more than happy to help you write a script, but what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, but you can do it in one `update` statement:

```
update table t left outer join
       table tc
       on t.a = tc.a and t.b = tc.b and tc.c is not null left outer join
       table tb
       on t.a = tb.a and t.c = tb.c and tb.b is not null
    set t.c = coalesce(t.c, tc.c),
        t.b = coalesce(t.b, tb.b);
```

This query does self joins to find the new values according to the rules you specified.  Each join brings in one of the values.  If there are multiple matching rows, then an arbitrary value from one of the several rows is chosen.

You can see what happens by running a `select` first:

```
select *
from   table t left outer join
       table tc
       on t.a = tc.a and t.b = tc.b and tc.c is not null left outer join
       table tb
       on t.a = tb.a and t.c = tb.c and tb.b is not null;



set c = (case when c is null
              then (select c from
```